# ExpressJS: localhost didn’t send any data

Tags: node.js, express

I am writing an app, when I start the server, its working nicely, its connecting to database. But when I start `http://localhost:5000` from the browser, it does not respond for a minuite then  the browser shows a message:

```
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Here is my **app.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(express.json());



//const userRouter = require('./routes/user');
//app.use('/user', userRouter);

const startApp = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://username:pass@cluster0-dcytp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        { useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: true });
        console.log(`successfully connected to database`);
        const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`server runnin at ${port}`);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}

startApp();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("I am in the root");
    res.send("hello World");
})
```

Why server is not responding from the browser?

Comment: You might want to change your password if those are your real credentials.

Comment: These are not real pass or user. :)

Comment: Your password is still in the edit history. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62098528/1

Comment: Can you confirm (from the logs) that your server is running and that `I am in the root` is logged when calling the endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
app.use(cookieParser())
```

instead of

```
app.use(cookieParser)
```

[Reference](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem db is connected but not able to send data. it looks weird but it works for me.

**Add a new database user with new password, use the new userName and passw to connect your mongoodb**
[this is the exact like to add new database user](https://cloud.mongodb.com/v2/5ecebfbd9aeac30e994075ce#security/database/users)

here is my db connection may it helps you too

```
mongoose.connect(DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true  })
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (error) => console.error(error))
db.once('open', () => console.log('connected to database'))

app.use(express.json())
```